# R mutate list of tables based on a date vector

Tags: r, list, dictionary, purrr, dplyr

```
list(tibble(x = 1,y =2),tibble(x = 3 , y= 4),tibble(x = 5,y = 6))

dates = seq(as.Date("2020-02-04"),as.Date("2020-02-06"),1)
```

I have a list of tables and would like to add a column were each table takes 1 value along the dates sequence, resulting in table1 having a date column filled with 2020-02-04 ,table2 with 2020-02-05 and table3 with 2020-02-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the map2 function from the purrr package, does this work?

```
library(tidyverse)

old_list <- list(tibble(x = 1,y =2),tibble(x = 3 , y= 4),tibble(x = 5,y = 6))

dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-04"),as.Date("2020-02-06"),1)

new_list <- map2(old_list, dates, function(x, y){
  x[["date"]] <- y
  x
})

new_list

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x     y date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1     1     2 2020-02-04

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x     y date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1     3     4 2020-02-05

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x     y date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1     5     6 2020-02-06
```

Comment: Yes exactly, Thank you!